# Using Open SSL with Xcode 4.3

Tags: objective-c, openssl, xcode4.2, osx-lion

Recently i upgraded Xcode from 3.2 to 4.3

My Application using openSSL 1.0.0 and was working fine with Xcode 3.2 , even XYZ.App which is making use of open SSL and built on Xcode 3.2 also working fine with OSX lion 10.7

But when i built the same application over Xcode 4.2 , the log says , it couldn't get certificates from the Authority , in-tunrs it seems to be that open-SSL library has not integrated properly with Xcode 4.3 application development environment,

I tried re-built openSSL but no luck, i am suspecting following,

1 -- In my Xcode 4.3 i could see only two compiler LLVM 4.3 and Apple LVM , i believe open SSL built using GCC 4.2 and on Xcode 3.2 i was using the same so it was working ,

2 -- On Lion should i do any kind of cross compilation for open - SSL with Apple LLVM Compiler , which should be working on the Xcode 4.3 application

Please throw any lights on it.

Comment: openSLL 0.9.7 is working (at least the parts I use) fine under Xcode 4.3/Lion 10.7 - though it is deprecated under 10.7. Maybe try linking with 0.9.7 and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @CRD, Which compiler did you use

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

The problem is,
**SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations** and **SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths**, the input parameter were not correct, 
In 10.6 it was compiling and running, might be SSL would have ignored it, in 10.7 it didn't work, 
Now i am giving proper input so working.

Thanks for reading it.